# Filling a character array with characters from a string

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to fill an array with characters from a string inputted via console. I've tried the code bellow but it doesnt seem to work. I get Index out Of Range exception in the for loop part, and i didn't understand why it occured. Is the for loop range incorrect? Any insight would be greatly appreciated

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a string: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var intoarray = new char[name.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i <= intoarray.Length; i++)
            {
                intoarray[i] = name[i];
            }
            foreach (var n in intoarray)
                Console.WriteLine(intoarray[n]);
```

Comment: Convert `name` to `ToCharArray()` directly.

Comment: also, as you start from 0, you need to stop at `intoarray.Length - 1`, so your for-loop should by like `for (var i = 0; i < intoarray.Length; i++)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using `ToCharArray()` strings can be converted into character arrays.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a string: ");
var name = Console.ReadLine();

var intoarray= name.ToCharArray();

foreach (var n in intoarray)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

if you are using foreach, you should wait for the index to behave as if you were taking the value.

```
Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since arrays start at 0 and you are counting inclusive of length, the last iteration  will exceed the bounds.
Just update the loop conditional to be less than length rather than less than or equal to..

Answer (score 2):

I like snn bm's answer, but to answer you question directly, you're exceeding the length of the input by one. It should be:

```
        for (var i = 0; i <= intoarray.Length - 1; i++)
```

(Since strings are zero-indexed, the last character in the underlying array is always going to be in the position of arrayLength - 1.)

Answer (score 1):

- 1: the iteration should be `for (var i = 0; i < intoarray.Length; i++)`
- 2: the code

  `foreach (var n in intoarray)
              Console.WriteLine(intoarray[n]);`

  also throws an exception, for "n" is a character in the array while it's used as array index.
- 3: In addition there's a much easier way to convert string to char array

  `var intoarray = name.ToCharArray();`

  [Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpT2q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake. There are so many options to represent `i < intoarray.Length`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < intoarray.Length; i++) // original was i <= intoarray.Length in your code
{
    intoarray[i] = name[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With linq:

```
  // Select all chars
  IEnumerable<char> intoarray =  
    from ch in name  
      select ch;  // can use var instead of IEnumerable<char>

    // Execute the query  
    foreach (char temp in intoarray)  
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
```